# bind multiple sparql variables into one so this one variable can be used to order results

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web

Basically I have some data like:

```
:student1 :hasAScore "4.1"
:student2 :hasAScore "2.7"
:student2 :hasBScore "2.1"
```

but in my query, I would like to

```
select * where{
  ?a :hasAScore ?score1
  ?b :hasBScore ?score2
  //bind ?score1 as ?score and bind ?score2 as ?score too, so they can be ranked by "order by"
} order by(?score)
```

basically i am saying i want to be able to rank students by a score which can be either AScore or BScore. is there anyway i can have some kind of union of ?score1 and ?score2 as ?score so that I can rank by ?score

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there anyway i can have some kind of union of ?score1 and ?score2
>   as ?score so that I can rank by ?score

Sure, you can use the appropriately named `union`, as in the following.  I'm assuming that you meant that the same student has both A scores and B scores, so that you actually wanted one variable in the subject position.

```
select * where { 
  { ?student :hasAScore ?score } 
  union 
  { ?student :hasBScore ?score }
}
```

You don't even need to use a `union` here, though.  In SPARQL 1.1, property paths were introduced, which means that you can write `:hasScoreA|:hasScoreB`, as in:

```
select * where { 
  ?student :hasAScore|:hasBScore ?score
}
```